# Android studio manifest file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-manifest

Right now I am using Android studio to learn Android Development. But I am using tutorials which are using Eclipse with android plugins. In that eclipse can give a UI view to a manifest file of a project. Is there anyway I can get that UI view of manifest file in Android Studio too or is it not a feature in Android Studio ?

Comment: The manifest files in Eclipse and Android Studio are usually no different.

Comment: Are you referring to XML Files for the UI or the Manifest File itself?

Comment: there are many good Android Studio tutorial available. Why you going for eclipse one if you are using Android Studio? Check this link http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/05/android-studio-tutorial/

Comment: UI view of the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think you talking about below functionality of Eclipse

> NO FOR ANDROID STUDIO :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to work directly with XML. AFAIK there is no UI interaction to edit the manifest

Comment: but I have seen in some tutorials that they are using a UI view of manifest file in Eclipse.....

Comment: You have in eclipse. But its not there in Studio

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no UI view of manifest in Android Studio. But the format of Android manifest is same. Take a look that [App Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). You can get everything you need.